# Error 500 when using Alias and Rewrite nginx

Tags: http, nginx, webserver

I'm trying to use URL Rewrite with multiple directories in my Nginx but when I apply it I get an error 500.

```
server {

    server_name mydns.com.br;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/godaddy-chained.crt ;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key ;

    root /var/www/manuais/index-site/;

    location /folder1/ {
    alias /var/www/manuais/folder1/;
        rewrite /folder1/?(.*) /$1 break;
        index index.html;
        satisfy any;
          allow myIP;
          allow myIP;
          deny all;
          auth_basic "Auth";
          auth_basic_user_file myAUTH;
    }

    location /folder2/ {
    alias /var/www/manuais/folder2/;
        rewrite /folder2/?(.*) /$1 break;
        index index.html;
        satisfy any;
          allow myip;
          allow myip;
          deny all;
          auth_basic "Auth";
          auth_basic_user_file myAuth;
    }
}
```

```
500 - Internal Server error
[alert] 2240016#2240016: *14432784 "alias" cannot be used in location "/folder1" where URI was rewritten, client: IP, server: mydns.com.br, request: "GET /folder1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "mmydns"
```

Is there any other way to rewrite this rule?

Comment: I've tried to change Alias by Root but I was not successful.

Comment: When I change the configuration to use Root (/) without directory (folder1) it works normally.  But I only have 1 dns and I need each folder to serve a directory.